# LAN to LAN VPN connectivity issues

Tags: vpn, ping, route, static-routes

I have a route-based VPN with limited functionality.

My computers on site-A can ping one workstation on site-B, it happens to be the only workstation that is not part of the domain that has been setup. To reiterate, I cannot ping computers that are all on the same domain.

Does anyone know why this could be?

None of the computers on site-B can get online (except for maybe the one pingable machine, however, no one at site-B can seem to find that computer physically to test it...)

Comment: Do the domain-joined machines have their firewalls enabled?

Comment: yes, but I don't think that's an issue only because the vpn was working, then we moved site-A to a new office, and now it does not (after making changes of course).

Answer (score 0):

I would check for the following things :

1. Firewall between you and the host name from your domain
2. DNS issues , as you can't ping the stations which are in a domain ... probablly DNS server issues , try to ping them on IP
3. Local policy on the domain that prevents ping , lookups from outside the domain.
4. If the VPN connection forwards ICMP requests (ping ) , but they seem to work because you can add that station from outside of the domain . Try to run a tracert to the station outside the domain than to those from the domain (both based on IP's).
5. Get Wireshark , nmap and check the packets that your sending ... (this might take some time to process)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into those processes. If it helps, when I try to ping these computers I ping them by IP so I don't think it's a dns issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't machines from site B get online??

How is this tunnel setup?

1. Are each of the sites each connected to a public WAN and the tunnel connects the two offices for Intranet resources, or
2. Is there a dedicated link between the two offices and Site B has to connect to Site A to get to the Internet?